# How to get rid of W11 when compiling latex using vim-latex-suite

Tags: vim, latex-suite

When compiling from vim using latex-suite (with the command `<leader>ll`) I often get the following error:

> W11: Warning: File "yourLaTeXfile.log" has changed since editing started
>   See ":help W11" for more info.

How can I configure vim/latex-suite to always set the autoread of the log-files produced by `Tex_RunLaTeX()`? Would it be sufficient to re-map `<leader>ll` to `Tex_RunLaTeX()!` or will that introduce any new cool features?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I configure vim/latex-suite to always set the autoread of the log-files produced by `Tex_RunLaTeX()`?

Find out which filetype is set for the file:

```
:setl filetype?
```

Then set up an autocmd:

```
:autocmd FileType <the-filetype-here> setlocal autoread
```

Alternatively, you can also directly define the autocmd on the file pattern `:autocmd BufRead *.log ...`, or append the `:setlocal autoread` directly to the `<Leader>ll` mapping.

Comment: My `<Leader>ll` is mapped like this, `nmap <Leader>ll ' :update!<CR>:call Tex_RunLaTeX()<CR>` could it work to modify it like this: `nmap <Leader>ll ':update!<CR>:call Tex_RunLaTeX()<CR>:setlocal autoread'` as it is the spawned log file that causes the W11 not the current file.

Comment: Yes, you're only missing a trailing `<CR>`. Or use `... :call Tex_RunLaTeX()<Bar>setlocal autoread<CR>`.

Comment: No, that does not work. I'm compiling a tex file and the file causing the error is the logfile produced by `Tex_RunLaTeX()`.

Comment: Does `Tex_RunLaTeX()` automatically open the log file? If not, you indeed have to rely on some autocmds, like in my answer.

Comment: Yes, `Tex_RunLaTeX()` opens the log file (named the same as the tex-file with the extension log)