# How do I disable W11 in Vim

Tags: vim

In short, how do I disable Vim's W11 warning:

```
W11: Warning: File "path/to/file.c" has changed since editing started
See ":help W11" for more info.
[O]K, (L)oad File:
```

This question has been asked a couple times before on StackOverflow (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17597452/can-i-disable-or-suppress-vim-w11-warnings) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510019/how-to-get-rid-of-w11-when-compiling-latex-using-vim-latex-suite)) as well as on a couple other forums. All answers I've seen either describe how to set up `autoread`, go into a discussion about why you shouldn't disable W11 warnings, and/or unhelpfully ask whether the person has looked at the Vim help page. This question is a case of "trust me, I know what I'm asking for."

As a bit of background, I commonly find myself working on or helping with 3 or 4 projects at the same time. Technically, `git worktree` is the nominal solution to this problem as it allows you to keep an arbitrary number of projects active at the same time in different directories so that you don't run into issues with multiple editors editing the same file. However, I've found `git worktree` creates more problems than it solves because I have to keep switching directories in a bunch of supporting terminals and it quickly gets confusing if I accidentally run a console from branch A with firmware from branch B. The safest thing has been to just `git checkout` the branch I want to work on. However, this results in probably 25 to 100 W11 warnings per day across my vim sessions or tens of thousands of false warnings per year. After the first few thousand warnings, it gets kind of old - especially when it basicaly never actually prevents loss of data.

Comment: Consider posting this question in https://vi.stackexchange.com/ (and if so, deleting it here).

Answer (score 2):

Those are not "false warnings". By checking out a version of your project that doesn't contain a given file or contains a different version of that file, you are effectively pulling the rug under Vim and yourself and `W11` is there to warn you before you do something nasty.

The functionality can't really be *disabled* at a low-level but there are ways to have it triggered less often, all listed under `:help W11`:

- `:help 'autoread'`, which doesn't help if files are changed in Vim,
- `:help 'buftype'`, which doesn't really have a satisfying "neutral" value that could be used for normal buffers instead of an empty value,
- `:help FileChangedShell`, which lets you decide exactly what happens when the current file has been changed outside of Vim *AND* disables the warning.

Your best bet is probably to use the autocommand option, a bit like this:

```
function HandleOutsideChange()
    edit
    " or do something smarter like checking
    " if the buffer is dirty, etc.
endfunction
augroup OutsideChange
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileChangedShell * call HandleOutsideChange()
augroup END
```

but I can see this becoming a very efficient footgun.

`git worktree` would be my go-to solution, here. I have been using it more and more for code reviews and it has been serving me very well so far.